# Unwanted special characters in WordPress site after export/import

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I made a copy of a WordPress site (originally at http://infinitelypossible.net) and changed the site URL to http://blissyourmoney.com.

Now there are unwanted special characters in the database, especially in the _posts table. Characters like quotation marks have been converted to other odd symbols, and some characters have just been added, seemingly randomly.

I double checked the export/import settings on WordPress.org for PHPMyAdmin and tried the export/import again with the correct settings, to no avail. (The only setting that needed to be changed was unchecking "Extended Inserts" under the Data heading.)

Comment: check the charsets of database and tables: they need to be the same as the old ones

Comment: Check to make sure that `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE` as defined in `wp-config.php` on the new site matches the old site.

Comment: @mbacon40 — I checked those and found that the old wp-config.php did not contain those lines at all. I commented them out in the new wp-config, and it removed the unwanted characters. Obviously that's not ideal, though, right? Is there a more thorough process that I could undertake that would fix this issue completely?

Comment: @Melodist See my answer to the question below. Commenting them out is what I would have done to fix the issue. Especially if it worked! However I added justification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my comment above: make sure that `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE` in `wp-config.php` on the new site matches the old site.

You responded that `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE` only existed in your new instal of WordPress and that removing them from the new `wp-config.php` fixed the issue. The issue was that you were instructing WordPress to use a different character set by having `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE` than what the database was setup with.

The WordPress Codex states, https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php:

> If DB_CHARSET and DB_COLLATE do not exist in your wp-config.php file, DO NOT add either definition to your wp-config.php file unless you read and understand Converting Database Character Sets. Adding DB_CHARSET and DB_COLLATE to the wp-config.php file, for an existing blog, can cause major problems.

So removing the definition to fix the issue was the right course of action and should solve the problem as you merely reset them to default values.

Comment: I accepted your answer, @mbacon40. Let me know if there's anything else to be done here.